# pgfplots: minor tick num on one axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, pgfplots, physics

I was just wondering if it was possible to use minor tick num on one axis only.

```
\begin{axis}[
axis x line = bottom,
axis y line = left,
minor tick num=4,
xlabel={$t(s)$},
xmin=0,xmax=5,
ylabel={$x(m)$},
ymin=0,ymax=15,
]
\end{axis}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `minor tick num`, you can use `minor x tick num=` to specify the minor ticks on just the `x` axis:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    minor x tick num=4,
    xlabel={$t(s)$},
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ylabel={$x(m)$},
    ymin=0,ymax=15,
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```